# no row at position zero after loop

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I need assistance with the following:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    PrepareDocument(dr);
}

//update table entries to processed state
try
{
    string constring = "........";
    string Query = @"update OnSiteWorkTx set Processed = 1 where VisitNumber = @company and Processed = 0";

    using (SqlConnection conDatabase = new SqlConnection(constring))
    using (SqlCommand cmdDatabase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDatabase))
    {
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", MyVariable);
        conDatabase.Open();
        cmdDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

Inside `PrepareDocument` I have the following:

```
private void PrepareDocument(DataRow dr)
{
    string connectWrk = ".............";

    using (SqlConnection connWrk = new SqlConnection(connectWrk))
    {
        string queryWrk = "SELECT Workdone FROM OnSiteWorkTx where VisitNumber='" + MyVarible + "' ";
        SqlCommand cmdWrk = new SqlCommand(queryWrk, connWrk);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdWrk);
        da.Fill(ds);

        var Workdone = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Workdone"];

        try
        {
            connWrk.Open();

            tableWrk.AddCell(cellWrk);
            tableWrk.AddCell(Workdone.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The code for changing the table entries to the processed state is running before `Preparedocument(dr)`, then the statement cannot find the entry for processed is now True and gives the error no row at postion zero.

Comment: Could you write the complete code of PrepareDocument?

Comment: var Workdone = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Workdone"];
 is the where the problem is.

Comment: you will have to check if a row exists at that position before using it. check if (da.count > 0) and then assign it to Workdone

Comment: There are numerous points that are not clear. Why do you loop over the rows of a table and pass a datarow to PrepareDocument when this row is not needed (and the query is always the same)? Why do you open the connection in the try/catch of PrepareDocument? Why don't you use a parameterized query like the one for the update also for the select?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    var Workdone = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];

    ...
```